# How do you export a complete data-model from Oracle APEX/SQL Workshop?

Tags: oracle, export, schema, oracle-apex, datamodel

I created a data model in Oracle APEX SQL Workshop, with a few simple tables and views.

I need to send this data model to somebody, so they can create the database objects in their own Oracle database environment, and build an APEX frontend application on top of it.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: You can do this in APEX but typically I use Oracle SQL Developer for this sort of thing as it's a bit more powerful and has more options to control the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Open **SQL Workshop**
2. Select **Utilities**
3. Select **Generate DDL**
4. Click **Create Script**
5. Follow the prompts (select all the objects if you want, or just the ones you need) to generate a SQL script